# What 1968 Moog synthesizer was used in the Movie Apollo 11?

Tags: history, synthesizer

I was watching the short YouTube video [How ‘Apollo 11’ Gives the Moon Landing New Life | Anatomy of a Scene](https://youtu.be/FHXN0u30vDM) and near the end the narrator says:

> My music composer, Matt Morton decided to do a period score, using only instrumentation that was around pre-1969, most notably, he went out and got a 1968 edition Moog synthesizer.

What 1968 Moog synthesizer is this?

---

I'm not sure if I should post this question here or in Movies SE. If there are Moog aficionados here they may know it right away, so I thought I would try here first. The only thing I can think of is the [cover of Switched On Bach](https://www.discogs.com/Walter-Carlos-Switched-On-Bach/release/7858).

[image: cover of Switched On Bach]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's a **Moog modular Synthesizer IIIc**

From [Matt Morton - Apollo 11](https://www.mattmortonmusic.com)

> Matt wrote, orchestrated, performed, recorded, and mixed all of the
>   original music for the film, as well as the teaser trailer and the
>   theatrical trailer.  Every instrument and effect used in the score
>   existed at the time of the mission in 1969 including the Moog modular
>   Synthesizer IIIc (see below), the Binson Echorec 2 (tube echo), the
>   Mellotron (early keyboard sampler used by The Beatles, Led Zeppelin,
>   etc.), and the orchestra.

I had a quick listen to this video & the trailer, and I have to say that all the synth noises I could pick out from this & under the orchestra could be made in VSTi these days (or certainly close enough for those of us without a Hollywood budget;) I have several plugins that can do Moog, ARP, Mellotron & the like, all really quite convincingly, if not as a single 'patch' then at least by layering.

Comment: And interesting comparison between real analog synths and virtual synth plugins is the difference between the *Stranger Things* (real) and *Dark Matter* (virtual) soundtracks.

Comment: Looks like I chose the right site to post, thanks very much!

Comment: I'd have probably struggled to choose too - but I'm on both, so you'd have got the same answer from me on either ;)

Comment: @uhoh and at Tetsujin, we seem to hang out in the same places :-)